# TikZ: node placement on path in matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-matrix

I have a problem with placing a node on a path drawn between two nodes in a TikZ matrix.  I want to show the correspondence between the edge of a directed graph and entries of its adjacency matrix.   My plan was to draw a dotted arrow between an edge of a digraph and the associated entry of its adjacency matrix.

I have two problems, one big, one small.  The biggest one is that in the MWE below I cannot correctly place a node on the curved edge between E and C.

```
    \draw[blue,thick] (E) to [bend right] (C);
    \node (ece) [pos=0.2] {} (E) -- (C); % (ece) is nowhere the edge :-(
```

A smaller problem for me is that I don't get why the node (mdag)-3-3 isn't drawn with a circle; it does get drawn in blue.

Here follows the full MWE.

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
    \matrix (dag)  [matrix of nodes,%
    nodes={outer sep=0pt,circle,minimum size=4pt,draw},
    column sep={2cm,between origins},
    row sep={2cm,between origins},
    ampersand replacement=\&] {
      |(A)| A \& |(C)| C \\
      |(D)| D \& |(E)| E \\
    };

    \draw (D) to [bend left] (A);
    \draw (E) to [bend right] (A);
    \draw[blue,thick] (E) to [bend right] (C);
    \node (ece) [pos=0.2] {} (E) -- (C); % (ece) is nowhere the edge :-(

  \matrix (mdag) at ([xshift=3cm]C.north east)
  [matrix of math nodes,
  anchor=TL.north west,
  every node/.style={font={\large\ttfamily}},
  row 3 column 3/.style={circle,blue}] {
    |(TL)|   &  A  &  C  \\
    D  &  1  &  0  \\
    E  &  1  & |(mce)| 1  \\
  };

  \draw[blue,fill] (ece) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[dotted] (ece) to [bend right] (mce.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto,
    C/.style = {%circle
                circle, fill=blue, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
    \matrix (dag)  [matrix of nodes,%
    nodes={outer sep=0pt,circle,minimum size=4pt,draw},
    column sep={2cm,between origins},
    row sep={2cm,between origins},
    ampersand replacement=\&] {
      |(A)| A \& |(C)| C \\
      |(D)| D \& |(E)| E \\
    };

    \draw (D) to [bend left] (A);
    \draw (E) to [bend right] (A);
    \draw[blue,thick] (E) to [bend right] node[C,right=1mm] (ece) {}  (C); % <--- see changes

  \matrix (mdag) at ([xshift=3cm]C.north east)
  [matrix of math nodes,
  anchor=TL.north west,
  every node/.style={font={\large\ttfamily}},
  row 3 column 3/.style={circle,blue}] {
    |(TL)|   &  A  &  C  \\
    D  &  1  &  0  \\
    E  &  1  & |(mce)| 1  \\
  };

  \draw[dotted] (ece) to [bend right] (mce.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Is this what you're looking for?

My node lies on the edge, yours doesn't determine any coordinate to be at. Correct placement of node is `\node at (<coordinate) {...};` but you wrote `\node (ece) [pos=0.2] {} (E) -- (C)` and `tikz` got lost... If you change it to `\path (E) -- node (ece) [pos=0.2] {}(C)`, the node does appear at 20% distance from `E` to `C`.

Comment: Yes, that's great.  Thanks a lot.  But I don't get why yours worked.  Or, more immediately, why mine didn't.  Nonetheless, thanks again.

Comment: see added explanation.

Comment: @healyp In my understanding, you're unhappily (might've worked but happens not to...) mixing the path syntax `--` with the node placement one `;)` Feel free to upvote if the answer helped (which obviously, it does, since you accepted !)